# Backbone - Overwrite Hashchange History

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, routes, browser-history, hashchange

Is it possible to rewrite the browser's history without using `history.pushState`?

I have a backbone application with a router that looks something like this:

```
routes: {
    'posts': 'posts',
    'modal': 'modal'
},

'before': function (args) {
    //check if logged in
        //do some various other setup tasks
    //maybe delete modal routes from the history?

    //forward to route
    args.next()
},

'posts': function () {
    //make and show posts
},

'modal': function (params) {
    //edit user email preferences OR
    //create a new post OR
    //do various other crud operations
}
```

Anytime the modal route is fired I'd like to prevent the hash from being written to the browser's history state. The reason being, users should not reopen the modal when traveling backwards in history.

I've looked through the backbone source code and I'm not seeing anything that simply says `history = []`.

Is there any way to do this without push state?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set the replace option to true of your router.navigate(fragment, [options]) function ?

This is supposed to update the URL without creating an entry in the browser's history

http://backbonejs.org/#Router-navigate

If you're handling a Button click event, that should be handle in a view and not in the router class.

Exemple :

```
class MyView extends Backbone.View

    events :

        'click #backButton'    :    'onClick'


    initialize : ->

           #Some Stuff


    render: ->

           #Some Stuff


    onClick: ( e ) ->

           router.navigate '/projects', {replace : true }
```

Comment: well, i'm sure that would work but isn't the navigate method only called when manually triggering a route? There are lots of instances in my application where I won't be able to do that (links which are share, come in via e-mail or other apps.)

Comment: How would I call that function when the back button is pressed?

Comment: I've juste updated my answer by adding and class exemple, and an onclick event on the '#myButton' button